# Prune leaf components of a directed graph

Tags: java, graph, graph-algorithm, directed-graph

Given a directed graph and some of its nodes, how to prune the nodes that cannot reach any of the given nodes. (I term it leaf components, which I am not sure is a correct term)

Are there any known algorithms solving this efficiently?

It would be perfect if you could point out some Java Open source code for it.

Thanks.

Comment: I've implemented this for OSM data to eliminate small subnetworks: https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/routing/util/PrepareRoutingSubnetworks.java

Answer (score 2):

Start a Breadth First Search or a Depth First Search starting from your given set of nodes and mark all nodes that the search traverses. Afterwards all non-marked nodes are not reachable from your given set of nodes and can be pruned. If *n* are the number of vertices and *m* the number of edges, this would solve your problem in *O(n + m)*.

I personally prefer [Tinkerpop Blueprints](http://blueprints.tinkerpop.com) as my main library for Graph processing in the JVM/Java/Scala.

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right, you need to find the [Strongly Connected Components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component), which can be found in O(n + m) time by doing 2 depth-first searches.